# Android XPath help required

Tags: android, xml, xpath

I am really new to android development, I am using Android 2.2 so have the option to develop with XPath which I think would be a good option.

The code I am wishing to extract is in the format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ams xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> 
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="XSLDoc.xsl"?> 
    <toGo>

        <SMS> 
            <ID>1</ID> 
            <to>07700000008</to> 
            <body>Hi Alice, This is just a test message.</body> 
        </SMS>

        <SMS> 
            <ID>2</ID> 
            <to>07700000009</to> 
            <body>Hi Bob, This is just a test message.</body> 
        </SMS>

    </toGo> 
</ams>
```

I have looked at the XPath API and their Foo example was not good enough for me to work it out. Anyone used XPath to collect information like this and maybe store it in an arraylist ?

If you feel my XML is awful, feel free to suggest a better structure with your reply/comments. Constructive criticism welcomed!

Thanks in advance,

EDIT:
There may be 0,1,2, or 500+ SMS blocks generated at a time.

Comment: So, which nodes do you want to select? Please, define the question better.

Comment: I need to extract all of the data preferably in a format:
mySMSArray.add(ID,to,body);
for each SMS block.

Comment: For future questions: XPath only selects nodes or gets evaluated to atomic data types (string, number and boolean in XPath 1.0). If you want to translate some node instances into another data type from the host language, then that would be clearly a host language task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to SamG who pointed me in the right path, pardon the pun.

His answer was 70% accurate and I would not have been able to manage it without his help. If anyone else is after the solution:

ArrayList smsList = new ArrayList();

```
DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("myXMLFile.xml");

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//SMS");

NodeList nodes = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);    
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

                   NodeList items = nodes.item(i).getChildNodes();

                   String id = items.item(1).getTextContent();
                   String to = items.item(3).getTextContent();
                   String body = items.item(5).getTextContent();

                   SMS sms = new SMS(id,to,body);

                   smsList.add(sms);
                }
```

I have no idea why the nodes get counted 1,3,5 instead of 0,1,2. But this solution works for me and hopefully might help others in future. If anyone else is able to explain why it is working, I would gratefully accept your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making an SMS object and creating an ArrayList of those objects. You can then parse the XML with something like this.

```
ArrayList<SMS> smsList = new ArrayList<SMS>();

DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse("myXMLFile.xml");

XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//SMS");

NodeList nodes = (NodeList)expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);


for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

   NodeList items = nodes.item(i).getChildNodes();

   String id = items(0).getNodeValue();
   String to = items(1).getNodeValue();
   String body = items(2).getNodeValue();
   SMS sms = new SMS(id,to,body);

   smsList.add(sms);    
}
```